# Can't change activity background colour to default

Tags: android

I am building a mobile app. Everywhere in the app I have the default background colour #F6F6F6. I have this colour stored in `colors.xml`.

```
<color name="backgroundColor">#F6F6F6</color>
```

I am now adding an onboarding guide using ViewPager. So I have an activity with ViewPager and a FrameLayout below with some other stuff in there. The problem is that when the application loads, the ViewPager has a different colour than it should have. It has darker grey `#E4E4E4`. And the FrameLayout has background just white `#FFFFFF`. When I set their background colour in the layout to any random colour - red, green, beige, that works and the colour is changed in the app.

**Works:**

```
android:background="@color/Red"
```

But if I try to set the colour to the default background colour or white, it doesn't work. Even if I hardcode the colour. The colour in the app doesn't change. Both views keep the colours I mentioned above.

**Doesn't work:**

```
android:background="#F6F6F6"
```

nor

```
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
```

The app and the activity is using the following theme:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Why can't I change the background colour to the colours I need?

Comment: Some clarification: Where are you putting android:background? Because both of those should work if they are placed in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new theme and change the background at theme level.

Note: this an example with a material theme, but it may not differ a lot from the support version.

```
<!-- themes.xlm -->    
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        
        <!-- ... other theme attributes -->
        <!-- ... changing theme window background. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_color</item>
    </style>
<!-- ... -->
</resources>
```

In your activity

```
<application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            ...
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
```